# Python. Numpy. Название столбцов

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Допустим есть numpy массив:

```
a = np.array([[1.2, -3.5, 0., -10.],
              [0.4, 2.1, -0.1, 0.5],
              [0., 1.1, 1., 1.5]])
```

Как дать названия столбцам 1,2,3,4? Я использовал

```
a = np.insert(a, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4], 0)


[[  1.    2.    3.    4. ]
 [  1.2  -3.5   0.  -10. ]
 [  0.4   2.1  -0.1   0.5]
 [  0.    1.1   1.    1.5]]
```

После я хочу сделать какую-нибудь операцию со столбцами, например сложить 1 и 3 столбцы

```
    [[  [1,3]   2.   4. ]
     [  1.2  -3.5   -10.]
     [  0.3   2.1    0.5]
     [  1.    1.1   1.5]]
```

Далее сделать так:

```
    [[  [1,3,4]   2. ]
     [  -8.8   -3.5  ]
     [  0.8     2.1  ]
     [  2.5     1.1  ]]
```

Т.е я хочу видеть какие столбцы объединил. Добавлять лист как я хочу numpy не дает. Как это можно реализовать? Может быть какие другие библиотеки. Задавать dtype мне кажется не подходит для этого или я в нем плохо разобрался. Но я бы хотел использовать numpy массив из-за удобных функций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) создан для работы с табличными данными (2D и 1D массивами). 2D таблицы в Pandas называются `DataFrame` и представляют из себя набор проиндексированных и именованных столбцов. Каждый столбец под капотом - это 1D Numpy вектор, у которого есть наименование и индексы. В Pandas эти объекты-столбцы называются `Series`.

Пример:

```
In [129]: a = np.array([[1.2, -3.5, 0., -10.],
     ...:               [0.4, 2.1, -0.1, 0.5],
     ...:               [0., 1.1, 1., 1.5]])

In [130]: df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[1,2,3,4])

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
     1    2    3     4
0  1.2 -3.5  0.0 -10.0
1  0.4  2.1 -0.1   0.5
2  0.0  1.1  1.0   1.5

In [133]: res = pd.DataFrame({"sum_1_3_4": df[[1,3,4]].sum(axis=1), 2: df[2]})

In [134]: res
Out[134]:
   sum_1_3_4    2
0       -8.8 -3.5
1        0.8  2.1
2        2.5  1.1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое